# MsBuild not working with NUnit in Teamcity

Tags: msbuild, continuous-integration, nunit, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I am beginner for TeamCity. And I have successfully setup TeamCity to build a Hello World ASP.NET MVC project. But once I added a NUnit test project in the solution, TeamCity always complains: NUnit relevant references are missing(which I absolutely don't miss them in the code) see following screenshot:

[image]

My NUnit project is very simple. Just one class:

[image]

And the TeamCity error is:

[image]

My configuration in TeamCity is very simple. I have just one Build Step using MsBuild:
[image]

I have tried to use MsBuild locally to run the project. It works well.

So what could be the problem of buiding it in TeamCity? I don't expect NUnit tests to run in the MsBuild step in TeamCity. As I know, I can creat another Build Step using NUnit runner to do it. Now I just want to pass the first MsBuild Step.

My environment:

- Visual Studio 2015 community
- .Net 4.6
- NUnit 2.6.2
- TeamCity 9.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restore NuGet packages. Try adding `NuGet Installer` step. You will probably have to select NuGet version in `https://teamcity.example.com/admin/admin.html?item=nugetServerSettingsTab&nuget-section=nuget-exe`

Comment: Thank @J2ghz, it's exactly what you said. I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

Your project is referencing NUnit, but it doesn't exist in the relative path of your project root.

First, add [NUnit as a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnit/2.6.2) then add a `NuGet Installer` build step before MSBuild to restore packages on your .sln file.

Comment: Thank @KMoraz, I already have NUnit package installed. I just need to add NuGet Installer Build Step before the MSBuild step. It worked now.